# Can I name each thread in this example?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

I want to create 10 threads with different names. Name should be a combination of `name` and `id.ToString()`

If I make a thread using `Thread t = new Thread()` then I know that I can do `t.Name = name + id.ToString();`, but if I there is some way to do it with the code example below I would love to know it.

```
            string name = "Thread #";
            int id = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
                    {
                        //Do something
                    }

                }).Start();   
            }
```

Comment: `var thread = new Thread(() =>`, then `thread.Name = $"Thread {i}"` before `thread.Start()`

Comment: I have tried to implement what you wrote but I don't understand it apparently, because it does not work. 
Can you implement it into my example? Sorry, I am super new at programming and all this is very slippery to me

Comment: See JonasH's answer - they demonstrate what I was trying to describe

Answer (score 6):

you could do

```
var t = new Thread(...);
t.Name = "Thread " + i;
t.Start();
```

But you should probably use the thread pool instead of creating explicit threads. In this specific case where you have a loop, you should probably use a [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop). In general when you want to run something on a background thread you should use [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0), or in some cases [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). When using the task pool you should not name threads, since the threads may be reused for other things. See [How can I assign a name to a task in TPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762286/how-can-i-assign-a-name-to-a-task-in-tpl) for similar concept for tasks.

Using the thread pool reduces the overhead for running things in the background, and usually also provides interfaces that are easier to use.

Answer (score -1):

I just added `Thread t = Thread.CurrentThread;` and then I could do `t.Name = $"Thread #{id}";` after.
This is what it looks like in its' entirety:

```
            int tId = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Thread t = Thread.CurrentThread; 
                    tId++;
                    t.Name = $"Thread #{tId}";
                    Console.WriteLine($"{t.Name}");
                }).Start();
```

Comment: incrementing numbers is not thread safe without some kind of synchronization. If this is news to you I would highly recommend staying away from multi threaded programming until until you have some basic understanding of thread safety.

Comment: I understand, thank you. 
However, this was what I needed to do in my homework assignment. This was just a first introduction to threading from our teacher - I am sure we are diving into tread security down the road.

Comment: If this is an assignment I would argue your teacher needs to update the material to teach current techniques. I would also argue thread safety need to be introduced very early, So I would encourage you to find [third](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices) [party](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) information. Also note that [safety != security](https://www.perforce.com/blog/kw/software-safety-vs-security-whats-different)